# "enter at least undefined characters" says mobile site below comment box

Tags: bug, mobile-web

This isn't a bug per se, more of a nuisance I would say.

To reproduce:

- open stackoverflow on mobile (I'm using chrome on Android, saw on other browsers on Android, not sure if the same occurs with iOS)
- open any question
- tap "add a comment" on the question
- see the note below the comment box: "enter at least undefined characters"

**Edit:** happens in desktop too with various mobile devices using dev tools

[image: enter at least undefined characters image]

Comment: cross site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332701/empty-comment-field-has-notice-enter-at-least-undefined-characters

Comment: That could take a long time... or a short time... I'm not sure ;).

Comment: @Monkey what could take long or short time? Fixing it?  As far as I am concerned, it's a minute fix.

Comment: If you're going to @ mention, you need to use the first part of a person's user name for them to get notified... It was an "undefined" joke. Never mind :).

Comment: @Heretic I know the @ mention thing, I just used your _second name_ because that's more interesting ;) BTW, can I call you Mr. Monkey? :D And your "undefined" joke was hilarious, though I didn't get it first time.